DC-DC voltage converter design advice
I am planning to build a DC power source for EDM/plasma polishing.
Both processes require a DC power source with difference being that plasma polishing needs voltage to be 300 to 400 DC
and for EDM voltage up to 120DC should be enough.
A while back I successfully removed a broken thread tap with 20VDC psu.
Rather than asking how-to I'm looking for input/advice to avoid obvious pitfalls.
As I'd like to keep this a 1 phase input (230VAC) so the voltage range needed would mean buck/boost converter
Is it better to make 2 separate converters, 1 for each voltage range?

Why do you want to make them as opposed to buying them? And what current are they supposed to deliver?
